# Set cell type in Axlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I need to create a excel sheet with the following headers:
`Date, Check in, Break in, Break out, Check out, Note`

Below those headers I want to add 100 empty rows of which the first column must be type: `date` and the other 5 columns must be type: `text`. For some reason only the first column of type: `date` is having the correct type when I open the file.

```rb
# template.xlsx.axlsx
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.styles do |style|
  heading = style.add_style(b: true)
  @profiles.each do |profile|
    wb.add_worksheet(name: "#{profile.firstname} #{profile.lastname} #{profile.id}") do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row ['Datum', 'Check in', 'Break in', 'Break out', 'Check out', 'Notitie'], style: heading
      100.times do
        sheet.add_row ['', '', '', '', '', ''], types: [:date, :text, :text, :text, :text, :text]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the column type using `col_style` in the sheet ([docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx%2FWorksheet:col_style), [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494822/axlxs-gem-automatically-add-date-columns)).

```rb
sheet.col_style(0, nil, type: :date, format_code: 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

You script with the changes:

```rb
# template.xlsx.axlsx
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

wb.styles do |style|
  heading = style.add_style(b: true)
  @profiles.each do |profile|
    wb.add_worksheet(name: "#{profile.firstname} #{profile.lastname} #{profile.id}") do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row ['Datum', 'Check in', 'Break in', 'Break out', 'Check out', 'Notitie'], style: heading
      sheet.col_style(0, nil, type: :date, format_code: 'dd/mm/yyyy')
      100.times do
        sheet.add_row ['', '', '', '', '', ''], types: [:date, :text, :text, :text, :text, :text]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That gives me the following error: `Invalid Data nil for unsigned_int. must be Integer.`